# I have a 2x2 positive-semidefinite matrix. I am trying to find the equation of its elements.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, symmetry

So long story short. I have a matrix $A \in S^2_+$, that is, a symmetric, positive semi-definite 2x2 matrix. Here it is: $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\y & z \end{bmatrix}$. Here is what it 'looks like' apparently.

[image]

I have two problems:

- The first one is that I would like to find out the constraints of the $x,y$, and $z$. For example, that $x \geq0$, $z \geq0$, and the same for $y$. I do not know how to find this. I have tried multiple things like using the characteristic polynomial etc, but no dice. I know that the eigenvalues must be $\geq0$ etc, but...
- Once I know what the x,y and z are, I think I will be able to interpret this diagram.

That is all, I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2x2, it's pretty easy: not only must the diagonal elements be positive, but the determinant must be, too. So the third constraint is $xz-y^2 \ge 0$, or $y^2 \le xz$. Coupled with the nonnegativity constraints on $x,z$, you can also write this as $|y| \le \sqrt{xz}$.

Comment: Micheal thanks, but I have spent the last 1/2 hour trying to get that last constraint... I cant seem to get it! :-/ May you please elucidate?

Comment: What's the determinant of the matrix, expressed in terms of $x,y,z$?

Comment: $xz - y^2$ is the det of a PSD, and I believe it must be $\geq0$... right? ...But how they do we get the constraints on x and z then? Lastly, I was told that I needed to re-express this in terms of positive eigenvalues, which I did, and that is where I got lost... so I am not sure how to get constraints on x, y and z at the same time.

Comment: I am not sure what to tell you. That's the third constraint. The other two are just the nonnegativity constraints on $x$ and $y$. You are done. As for the eigenvalues, you just have to find the characteristic polynomial symbolically.

Comment: Let me rephrase: 1) Is it true that for a PSD matrix, its det must be >= 0? 2) Secondly, if that is the case, then yes, I agree that one of the constraints must mean that $y^2 \leq xz$. Ok, but where do you get the constraints that both x and z must be $\geq 0$? For example, why cant both x and z be negative? 3) Lastly, I think you have some minor typos in the answer vis-a-vis ys and zs.

Comment: You say for example "The diagonal elements must be positive". (This is the constraint on x and z). Fair enough, but why is that true? I looked at the wiki but cant find a rule anywhere that says a PSD matrix must have diagonal positive elements... that is what I am wondering about. Thanks again.

Comment: You need a better wiki, then! What definition of positive semidefiniteness do you know? I'm going to guess that you can use that to prove the nonnegativity of the diagonal elements without much trouble. (Incidentally, $y$ does *not* have to be positive.)

Comment: I just realized you are the author of CVX??! I am learning it actually! This is why I am asking this question! I'm a huge fan, and love your work! :-) What are the odds?? To answer your question: The definition of PSD I know are: 1) $x^T A x \geq0$. 2) Furthermore, I also know that all the eigenvalues of $A$ must also be $\geq0$. I tried to find the constraints on x y and z based on this definition actually.

Comment: Lastly regarding the wiki - to be honest, the fact that a PSD matrix needs to have diagonal elements that are $\geq0$ is news to me... Im just trying to find it on the page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices

Comment: So: given the $x^TAx\geq 0$ definition, what happens if $x=[1~0]^T$? What if it is $x=[0~1]^T$? As for the third constraint, the "principal minors" definition gives you that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13034/discussion-between-spacey-and-michael-c-grant)

Comment: Thanks for the help Micheal, it is much clearer now.

Comment: You're very welcome, and thanks for the kind words about CVX.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 \\
x_2 & x_3
\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite if and only if

$$z^T A z = z_1^2 x_1 + 2 z_1 z_2 x_2 + z_2^2 x_3 \ge 0$$

for all z. This can be reformulated as

$$x_1 (z_1 + z_2 \frac{x_2}{x_1})^2 - z_2^2 \frac{x_2^2}{x_1} + z_2^2 x_3 \ge 0 $$

so it is clear that we must have $x_1 \ge 0$ and

$$x_3 - \frac{x_2^2}{x_1} \ge 0$$

Similarly, we get $x_3 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, the determinant of a 2x2 PSD matrix must be >= 0.  2)  You where who specified that $x \geq 0$ and $z \geq 0$.  Also, if a matrix is PSD, all of its eigenvalues must be non-negative, and the trace of a matrix equals the sum of its eigenvalues.  So, $x$ and $z$ cannot both be negative.